# Regex to remove a whitespace from href link

Tags: javascript, regex

Can some one help me to create a regular expression in Javascript to remove a whitespace from href link and replace whitespace to hyphen to in my content?

For example:

```
<a class="card" href=http://www.eee.com/sffsd/sdfs/Aks's  Reb outsider/4234234234324>
```

it should convert it into

```
<a class="card" href=http://www.eee.com/sffsd/sdfs/Aks's-Reb-outsider/4234234234324>
```

Comment: What have you tried? `link.href = link.href.replace(/ /g, '-')` should be enough, no?

Comment: You want it in js but tagged as php; why? This shouldn't be so hard to Google "remove white space". You shown us no effort on your part.

Comment: @NewbeeDev `trim` is not solve this issue. `trim` is removing trailing and leading characters only.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem That will not work at all.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: The original question was tagged with `preg-match`, I thought of PHP automatically. Sorry, it seems my bad. Please add only relevant tags to avoid confusion.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No problemo ;-)

Comment: Oops, the *Please add only relevant tags to avoid confusion.* was addressed to @SarvaniAnnamraju. :) I need a break.

Comment: @SarvaniAnnamraju Why do you think it won't? You want to replace spaces in a href attribute of a link element, right?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things, like I said in the comment, replacing the spaces with dashes should be as easy as:

```
link.href = link.href.replace(/ /g, '-');
//or in php:
$href = preg_replace('/ /', '-', $href);
```

(JS only): using the `g` flag ensures the entire string is searched for spaces, and replaces them all with dashes.

The better question to ask is: ***how did the spaces get there in the first place?***

My first port of call would be to look at the code generating the markup, and fix the problem there. You shouldn't be writing code fixing the output of code that is broken. Fix the bug, don't accommodate it.

Arguably, the URL's should be properly escaped, rather tan using regex, the URI should've been passed through a function like `encodeURI` to convert all spaces to `%20` etc...

Comment: probably trying to generate seo friendly urls dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

use this regex format

```
link.href = link.href.replace(/\s/g, '-');
```

Comment: `\s` matches all [unicode space character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Zs/list.htm), not just spaces... That, and although not really relevant here writing `/ /` is shorter anyway